# golang build at /vendor/github.com/weaveworks/promrus is giving an error: undefined: logrus.Level

Tags: go, zos

I am trying to build the golang package (/vendor/github.com/weaveworks/promrus) in IBM Z (Mainframe). And I am getting an error: **./promrus.go:15:25: undefined: logrus.Level**
My go version is: go version **go1.16.2 zos/s390x**
I have tried to read through the article: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-go-zos/1.16?topic=porting-applications-zos
and have added a build constraint (//+build zos) as given below. But still the **undefined** error is not going away. Is there any way to build? Pls help and thanks in advance.

> //+build zos
>
> package promrus
>
> import (
> "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
> "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" )
>
> // PrometheusHook exposes Prometheus counters for each of logrus' log
> levels. type PrometheusHook struct {
> counterVec *prometheus.CounterVec }

Comment: Adding a random constraint to a file does not just make it work, and if it didn't have any constraints it was already being compiled. `/vendor/github.com/weaveworks/promrus` isn't a separate package to build, it's contained within another project's vendor folder, but vendoring isn't really used much any longer. What exactly are you trying to build?

Comment: I am trying to build Grafana in IBM Z where promrus is a package under vendor and I am getting this undefined error in a few other packages as well (promrus is only one of them). Hence as per the IBM article above I am adding a build constraint. Any way to build on a per package basis?

Comment: How are you building the project? There is no Go vendor directory in the grafana source.

Answer (score 0):

User opened up an official support Case with IBM and found resolution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).